# Sylvan CSV Reader C# Check for Missing Column in CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

@MarkPflug I have a requirement to read 12 columns out of 45 - 85 total columns. **This is from multiple csv files (in the hundreds)**. But here is the problem, a lot of the times a column or two will be missing from some csv data files. How do I check in C# for a missing column in a csv file given I use the nuget package [sylvan csv reader](https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/main/docs/Csv/Sylvan.Data.Csv.md). Here is some code:

```
// Create a reader
CsvDataReader reader = CsvDataReader.Create(file, new CsvDataReaderOptions { ResultSetMode = ResultSetMode.MultiResult });
// Get column by name from csv. This is where the error occurs only in the files that have missing columns. I store these and then use them in a GetString(Ordinal).
reader.GetOrdinal("HomeTeam");
reader.GetOrdinal("AwayTeam");
reader.GetOrdinal("Referee");
reader.GetOrdinal("FTHG");
reader.GetOrdinal("FTAG");
reader.GetOrdinal("Division");
// There is more data here, but anyway you get the point.
// Here I run the reader and for each piece of data I run my database write method.
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        await AddEntry(idCounter.ToString(), idCounter.ToString(), attendance, referee, division, date, home_team, away_team, fthg, ftag, hthg, htag, ftr, htr);
    }
```

I tried the following:

```
// This still causes it to go out of bounds.
if(reader.GetOrdinal("Division") < reader.FieldCount)
    // only if the ordinal exists then assign it in a temp variable
else
    // skip this column (set the data in add entry method to "")
```

Comment: Sylvan *does* have an issue tracker y'know, you don't have to @ the authors here.. :)

Comment: *Get some data from csv using column name* - my experience of Sylvan is like DataReader; you getordinal to get the column number where the data is, but you get the data itself by something like `GetString(the_ordinal_number_here)`.. As such I'm not sure what those GetOrdinal statements will *do* on their own

Comment: Did you see the *Error Handling* part of the Sylvan.Data.Csv.md (you linked to it in the Q) - it has, near the end: "**Missing Fields**

A missing field, meaning a row that contains fewer columns than the header column will be treated the same as if it were an empty string. Missing fields can be identified by comparing the RowFieldCount to FieldCount.

**Extra Fields**

Extra fields, meaning a row that contains more columns than the header column, will be ignored. Extra fields can be identified by comparing the RowFieldCount to FieldCount. Extra field values can be accessed by ordinal."

Comment: I think you need to be looking at `reader.RowFieldCount` rather than `FieldCount` to determine if a particular row has more/fewer columns than the header does (but I've not touched that part of sylvan in my use of it)

Comment: (Also, the question is.. *which* column is missing.. And this is why CSV is crap)

Comment: @CaiusJard Your comment is correct, I have fixed my description of the methods. I don't have a problem with this, it was a miscommunication.

Comment: @CaiusJard It seems we have an even bigger miscommunication error here. The issue is not that some rows have more columns that others its more like some files have more columns than others. I should have mentioned that too I guess.

Comment: @NicktheCommunityScientist Caius's answer is correct. I would like to have GetOrdinal return -1 when the field is missing, but the BCL documentation indicates it should throw. You can write a "TryGetOrdinal" extension method to make it a bit easier though: https://gist.github.com/MarkPflug/a8122cb240e71de5d0333ed8d3e6deea

Comment: @NicktheCommunityScientist Also, "Ating" (@) people in the question doesn't work. I stumbled upon this purely by coincidence.

Comment: @MarkPflug Yes, I realized that the '@' notation in the question does not work indeed. Didn't know that. In the case that you wouldn't find my question and the community also didn't know. Then I would come to your repository directly on the issue tracker with this question, as was suggested by Caius Jard above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, it appears that GetOrdinal throws if the column name isn't found or is ambiguous. As such I expect you could do:

```
int blah1Ord = -1;
try{ blah1Ord = reader.GetOrdinal("blah1"); } catch { }

int blah2Ord = -1;
try{ blah2Ord = reader.GetOrdinal("blah2"); } catch { }

while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    var x = new Whatever();
    if(blah1Ord > -1) x.Blah1 = reader.GetString(blah1Ord);
    if(blah2Ord > -1) x.Blah2 = reader.GetString(blah2Ord);
}
```

And so on, so you effectively sound out whether a column exists - the ordinal remains -1 if it doesn't - and then use that to decide whether to read the column or not

Incidentally, I've been dealing with CSVs with poor/misspelled/partial header names, and I've found myself getting the column schema and searching it for partials, like:

```
using var cdr = CsvDataReader.Create(sr);

var cs = await cdr.GetColumnSchemaAsync();
var sc = StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase;
var blah1Ord = cs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ColumnName.Contains("blah1", sc))?.ColumnOrdinal ?? -1;
```

Comment: I will give it a go today and see what happens. Thanks for the time.

Comment: I need to tell you something. You are a god, my man. I used your first solution, and it's as beautiful as it gets. Fun fact, it's my first time working with CSV's and first encounter of C#. Anyway, so when you say looking at the source could you show me where is said source? (a link or something). Bet you all my money I was blind, and it was right in my face in the Git remote or something.

Comment: Starting to like Sylvan, and I'm still figuring out good ways to work with it. There are certainly plenty of CSV libs that take many different approaches, and even with sylvan you might be able to make your life easier with the Data Binder example from https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/main/docs/Csv/Examples.md - in essence define a class with properties of name matching the column header and type matching the column values and then Sylvan does the "column Xyz gets assigned to the Xyz property" bit. I expect that if the headers contain chars not allowed in properties there will be..

Comment: ..ways to account for it like putting an `[ColumnName("X-Y*Z")]` attribute on the Xyz property. I don't know what the binder will do if the column is entirely missing from the file; it'd be something to play with and see, maybe there is a `[Optional]` attribute or similar that tells sylvan to ignore/don't act if it's missing..

Comment: You asked about the source code - couple of ways. Have a read about [Source Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/sourcelink) - nuget package authors can essentially embed the source in the package and visual studio can step into it and show you it when debugging or if you right click on GetOrdinal and choose "Go to Definition/Implementation". The other way is to click on the "Code" tab on the GitHub page and browse around the repo in its natty filesystem sort of browser. You can click into files and even click on method calls in the code to peek/go

Comment: I'm sure my VS had source link for Sylvan as I used it a few days ago but then I cleared 15 gigs of cached nuget packages and it stopped working; I should probably look how to re enable it as it was useful when working with new libraries. Don't forget that because it's open source and github you can always hit Download (as zip) the repo and load it into your own solution as another project ("Add existing project") then add a reference from your project to the Sylvan project, instead of referencing the nuget package. This way you also can debug step into syl's code and see it work

Comment: @CaiusJard The source link probably broke because I forgot to upload the symbols packages for some recent versions.

Comment: @CaiusJard Regarding the data binder naming: the default behavior tries to be "smart" when it maps the column name to property names: https://github.com/MarkPflug/Sylvan/blob/db37f3f4708c0e30fb060c609667638e86af3a91/source/Sylvan.Data.Tests/DataBinderTests.cs#L100-L115

You can also specify an alternate name with System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute

Comment: And does it care if data is missing/do we have to specify a prop as optional somehow?

Comment: @CaiusJard Moved discussion in GH repo.

Answer (score 2):

I started using the Sylvan library and it is really powerful.
Not sure if this could help you but if you use the `DataBinder.Create<T>` generic method from an entity, you can do the following to get columns in your CSV file that do not map to any of the entity properties:

```
var dataBinderOptions = new DataBinderOptions()
{
    // AllColumns is required to throw UnboundMemberException
    BindingMode = DataBindingMode.AllColumns,
};

IDataBinder<TEntity> binder;

try
{
    binder = DataBinder.Create<TEntity>(dataReader, dataBinderOptions);
}
catch (UnboundMemberException ex)
{
    // Use ex.UnboundColumns to get unmapped columnns
    readResult.ValidationProblems.Add($"Unmapped columns: {String.Join(", ", ex.UnboundColumns)}");
    return;
}
```